# For Loop Not Terminating

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to get back into Java - it's been about 5 years since I studied the basics and I've been lost in the .Net world since.

I'm trying to create a student class below, however the for loop for reading in the integers into the array gets stuck when the program runs.

From my previous knowledge, and from research, the loop seems to be constructed properly and I can't seem to figure out where it's going wrong.

I'm sure it's something silly - as always but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction? :)

```
import java.util.*;
import acm.io.*;

public class Student {

    // instance variables 
    private int studNumber;     //Must be between (and including) 0 and 99999999. If input value invalid default to 0.
    private String studName;    
    private int marks[];   

    /*
     * Constructor Student Class
     */
    public Student(int studNumber, String StudName, int marks[])  {

        // initialise instance variables
        if (studNumber >=0 && studNumber<= 99999999) {
            this.studNumber= studNumber;
        } else {
            this.studNumber = 0; //default value
        }

        this.studName= StudName; // no validation
        this.marks = marks;

        IOConsole console = new IOConsole();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {  
            marks[i] = console.readInt();          
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `IOConsole`? What do you see when you try to debug this program?

Comment: @Peter, http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/io/IOConsole.html.

Comment: Do you actually provide any values while the program is stuck? The method `readInt` may read something from a console, do you see this console and input data?

Comment: @109221793, what do you mean gets stuck? readInt expects user input so you need to provide it, may be thats why it looks stuck?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments.I'm using a compiler called BlueJ which I'll be honest, I wouldn't have used before (more used to jGrasp). To create the student object in this compiler, you type the values into BlueJs new object dialog box. Do you think this makes a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the `readInt()` part. It's unusual to read input from the `Console` in a constructor for initializing the attributes, delegate that task to another part of your code and move it outside the constructor.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I'm using a compiler called BlueJ which I'll be honest, I wouldn't have used before (more used to jGrasp). To create the student object in this compiler, you type the values into BlueJs new object dialog box. Do you think this makes a difference? (apologies if this is a stupid question)

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. The problem lies in the fact that you're calling a blocking method, `readInt()`, inside a constructor, something that you should avoid - be aware that `console.readInt()` expects the user to type some values in console. Instead, let the object creation finish normally and later, in another method, ask the user for the initialization values and pass them to the `marks` array.

Comment: I get you. Thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem lies here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{  
    marks[i] = console.readInt();          
}
```

The only instance where I found a reference to IOConsole was [here](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/io/IOConsole.html) and it does not seem to be something which is part of the standard Java framework.

If you just need to scan numbers from console, you can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class and the use the [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method like below:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {  
        marks[i] = input.nextInt();          
    }
```

Comment: The one he uses is this : http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/io/IOConsole.html

Comment: Hi npinti, I'm using a compiler called BlueJ which I'll be honest, I wouldn't have used before (more used to jGrasp). To create the student object in this compiler, you type the values into BlueJs new object dialog box. Do you think this makes a difference? (apologies if this is a stupid question)

Comment: I do not think that it really makes a difference. Just for the sake of clarity, blueJ is an IDE, which honestly I have never used. I suggest you switch to Eclipse which is more common in the industry or else use, Netbeans which is Oracle's (Sun's) recommended IDE.

Answer (score 2):

The loop seems correct. Is it possible the `console.readInt()` call is blocking, which keeps you stuck in the loop (the `IOConsole` class is not part of the standard JDK, and I am not familiar with it)

Answer (score 2):

`readInt()` is waiting for user input

from http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/io/IOConsole.html#readInt%28%29:

> Reads and returns an integer value from the user

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with console.readInt(), where another non-stop loop is executing or some other problem with that method